# How to determine when Bash's "exit immediately" option (set -e) is being ignored

Tags: bash

The manual for the Bash shell provides the following information in the section that describes the `set -e` builtin option:

> If a compound command or shell function executes in a context where -e is being ignored, none of the commands executed within the compound command or function body will be affected by the -e setting, even if -e is set and a command returns a failure status. If a compound command or shell function sets -e while executing in a context where -e is ignored, that setting will not have any effect until the compound command or the command containing the function call completes.

I've encountered a problem with a Bash script I'm writing where I'm setting the `-e` flag, but the script does not exit when a command returns a non-zero exit status code.  This is occurring within a called function, e.g.,

*Listing 1*

```bash
set -e

function foo ()
{
    set -e
    ls zzzz     # 'zzzz' doesn't exist
    ...   # <- these statements are executed
}

foo
...  # <- these statements are executed
```

I know I can use Bash's builtin variable `$-` to display the options that are currently set. When I do this in my actual script, the `-e` option is set: `ehuB`.  Nevertheless, the called function does not exit when it executes a statement that returns a non-zero exit status. So, I'm assuming the called function must be executing within a context where `-e` is being ignored.

*Listing 2*

```bash
set -e

function foo ()
{
    set -e
    echo "settings=$-"    # ehuB
    ls zzzz     # 'zzzz' doesn't exist
    ...   # <- these statements are executed
}

echo "settings=$-"    # ehuB
foo
...  # <- these statements are executed
```

So my question is this: how can I programmatically test to determine that a section of code in a Bash script is or isn't executing within a context where `-e` is being ignored?

Additionally, what conditions create an execution context where the `-e` option (when set) is ignored?

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105 and look at the `Conclusions` below - `don't use set -e. Add your own error checking instead.`

Comment: Also which bash version are you running?

Comment: [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) explains in quite a bit of detail, but the basic summary is that the rules for when `-e` considers an error "exit-worthy" (my term) are complex, hard to understand, and not even consistent versions. Don't try to figure it out or try to get it to be consistent, it's more trouble than it's worth (and anyway it'll be different in the next version).

Comment: The rules for the (fairly uselss) `set -e` are pretty clear: In your example, if the file does not exist, `ls` yields exit code 1, and since this exit caught is not caught in the context of this statement, the script is supposed to terminate. It does so in my _bash_. Could it be that you have an `exit` trap installed? If not, please demonstrate using a screenshot that your bash behaves in the way you described (and, do a `echo $-` right before your `ls` command ... the devil never sleeps).

Comment: `This is occurring within a called function, e.g.` I can't reproduce. Did this change in some bash version?

Comment: BTW, you get a list of all your traps, by doing a plain `trap`, so do this in addition to printing `$-`.

Comment: Also `set -E` to propagate errors from functions. Check [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin)

Comment: FWIW, my Bash version is 5.2.15

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Unfortunately, the actual code is quite complex and proprietary, so I can't publish here a detailed example of the code that's not working.  I'm not using an `exit` trap. For debugging purposes, I've added copious `echo $-` statements in the code path leading up to (and within) the called function to track the state of the `-e` flag, but so far that hasn't yielded any useful clues as to why the called function fails to exit when an error occurs.

Comment: You understand that we're all recommending you do not use `set -e`, right? If you do still want a different answer, though - almost no-one posts their real code in a question, you're expected to come up with a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1):

> what conditions create an execution context where the -e option (when set) is ignored?

Is documented in:

> -e
>
> Exit immediately if a pipeline (see Pipelines), which may consist of a
> single simple command (see Simple Commands), a list (see Lists of
> Commands), or a compound command (see Compound Commands) returns a
> non-zero status. The shell does not exit if the command that fails is
> part of the command list immediately following a while or until
> keyword, part of the test in an if statement, part of any command
> executed in a && or || list except the command following the final &&
> or ||, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command’s
> return status is being inverted with !. If a compound command other
> than a subshell returns a non-zero status because a command failed
> while -e was being ignored, the shell does not exit. A trap on ERR, if
> set, is executed before the shell exits.
>
> This option applies to the shell environment and each subshell
> environment separately (see Command Execution Environment), and may
> cause subshells to exit before executing all the commands in the
> subshell.
>
> If a compound command or shell function executes in a context where -e
> is being ignored, none of the commands executed within the compound
> command or function body will be affected by the -e setting, even if
> -e is set and a command returns a failure status. If a compound command or shell function sets -e while executing in a context where
> -e is ignored, that setting will not have any effect until the compound command or the command containing the function call
> completes.

> How to determine when Bash's "exit immediately" option (set -e) is being ignored

This is like my decision tree:

- Is the command called from if, while or until? -> ignored
- Is the command prefixed with `!` ? -> ignored
- Is the command in assignment of export, declare, typeset or local? -> ignored
- Not ignored.

Also remember about inheritance:

- Is this an asynchronous command?

  - Is this a process substitution, like `echo < <(false; echo test >&2)`?
  - Is this inside a part of a pipeline, like `{ false; echo test >&2; } | echo`?
  - Is this inside coproc?
  - then set -e *is* inherited
- Are you in a subshell () ?

  - then is errexit_inherit set?

There is also a logic what is the actual exit status of chain of commands like.

- in 99% of contexts, the exit status of a block of commands is the exit status of last command executed
- What is the exit status of `a && b || c` vs `a || b && c`?
- Is lastpipe set?
- What is the exit status of `if` block? (last command executed). Ex. `set -e; ( if true; then false; fi )`?

Note that I am using `set -e` in *my* scripts. I am not forcing it on other people. And there *are* scripts that you *want* to continue when one of the commands fails.

> how can I programmatically test to determine that a section of code in a Bash script is or isn't executing within a context where -e is being ignored?

You can't.

You could write a bash builtin to access `exit_immediately_on_error` but it is reset here https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/ec8113b9861375e4e17b3307372569d429dec814/execute_cmd.c#L4890 before executing the builtin. Also, the checks are not really simple like https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/ec8113b9861375e4e17b3307372569d429dec814/execute_cmd.c#L2792 so I do not see a way.

Comment: Thank you.  This information is useful.  The code that's failing is executing within the context of a subshell--i.e., `result=$(foo)` and foo is the function that doesn't exit when an invoked process' exit status is non-zero.  I'll take a look at the `inherit_errexit` shell option (`shopt`) to see if maybe that's the issue.

Comment: Do `result=$(set -e; foo)`, but overall consider `foo result` and set result with `declare -n`

Answer (score 1):

I could have put this in comments area, but put as an answer for formatting purposes.

Can you run following script and post results :

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

trap

function foo ()
{
    set -e
    echo $BASH_VERSION
    ls zzzz     
    echo "After ls"
}

echo "$(foo)"
echo "After subshell of foo"

echo -e "\nNow, going to do a direct call..."

foo
echo "After direct call of foo"
```

Mine gives result :

```
ls: cannot access 'zzzz': No such file or directory
5.1.16(1)-release
After subshell of foo

Now, going to do a direct call...
5.1.16(1)-release
ls: cannot access 'zzzz': No such file or directory
Exit code : 2
```

Comment: Thanks.  This Fedora 38 host has Bash version `5.1.15(1)-release` installed.  And for what it's worth, when I create "simple" code examples like the one shown above, the code works correctly, which is why I'm scratching my head on this one.  My production code is organized essentially the same way, and yet it doesn't exit when a process returns a non-zero exit status.  I'm at the point where I'll probably end up stripping out a bunch of code, until I get the behavior I want, and then piece-by-piece re-add the removed code until something breaks.

Comment: I updated the answer with a subshell.